# Area between two longitudes?

Tags: coordinate-system, geometry, latitude-longitude, spherical-geometry, geography

I am trying to compute the area between two longitudes (using the angle between them) but am having a hard time. I can do that more easily between latitudes but longitude reveals to be tricky.

Anyone has a good reference formula for that one?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer to my own question. I have just been frantically searching with the wrong point of view. It is just a wedge from a sphere. So you can use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_wedge

This is for a rough order of magnitude and not exact obviously due to the "patatoid" shape of the earth

Comment: Well, except that the Earth *isn't* a sphere, so this route will involve error.

Comment: It will indeed, but do the trick for the moment being as a ROM. If someone has a good suggestion I'm all ears!